# Response.Redirect in HttpModule

Tags: asp.net, cookies, httphandler, httpmodule

Can I do a redirect to a custom page in an HttpModule?

I have an HttpModule A which executes some javascript code when any aspx page is loaded.
I would like to have a server side code check to see if the clients browsers supports cookies.
Can I place that code in the HttpModule A? If so, in which event?
Or do I need to have a new HttpHandler for both purposes?

Also, is it possible to check for cookies in an HttpModule(without a response.redirect)?
All solutions I have seen need 2 pages, 1 for setting the cookie and the other for checking if the cookie has actually been created. I am hoping there should be a way to check for cookies at one place.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Check this out..
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/030522.htm

The key being... 
Context.RewritePath()

MDSN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same HttpHandler for both.  The cookie check just needs to go in an event before the page handler gets called, such as the "BeginRequest" event.  Then you can use the Response.Redirect or Context.RewritePath.

Comment: Now suppose I want to do the cookie check for only certain aspx files in my project, what would be the best way? Have the selected files in web.config, have the list in a separate xml/config file, use the resources files?Also, can I use session in the HttpModule "BeginRequest" event?